# Can't connect to GCP cluster VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm following this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/running-rstudio-server-on-a-cloud-dataproc-cluster#creating_a_user_account_on_the_master_node) and can't connect to a GCP VM cluster using SSH port forwarding.

I run this command line:

```
$ gcloud compute ssh cluster-5b2b-m --zone=asia-northeast2-b \
--project=*** -- -L 8787:localhost:8787
```

but when I try to open 
`http://localhost:8787` in the browser i get an error saying `This site can't be reached`

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Can you access inside the vm?

Comment: Can you resolve/ping the host "localhost"?

Comment: Yes I can ssh into the vm, and I can ping the localhost ``ping localhost``. Opening the vm on an external browser tab is not working, however I managed to open the vm using the web preview button on cloud shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Example, the full command should be as following, then gcloud will open a tunnel to your cluster. I think you forget to type  **[CLUSTER_NAME]-m**

```
gcloud compute ssh \
    --zone=[CLUSTER_ZONE] \
    --project=[PROJECT_ID] \
    [CLUSTER_NAME]-m -- \
    -L 8787:localhost:8787
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah,
The issue is that you are trying to access to "localhost" in the browser but your cluster is in gcloud.

You can try to access using Rstudio: http://[CLUSTER_NAME]-m:8787 as the tutorial suggests, or http://[CLUSTER_NAME]-m:8088 from the browser, if the configuration is correct it should works.